# How to draw these coins?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanto to draw it, but

[image]

So I can make a part, but still without much quality

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


\begin{center}
\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(2,0) circle (1cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(1,1.7) circle (1cm)} \qquad
\def\firstcircle{(5,0) circle (1cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(7,0) circle (1cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(6,1.7) circle (1cm)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$K$};
    \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$K$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$K$};
    \end{tikzpicture} \qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw \firstcircle node[below] {$C$};
    \draw \secondcircle node [above] {$C$};
    \draw \thirdcircle node [below] {$C$};

\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{center}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you remove the options to the `node` the labels will be centered.

Comment: Excuse me, are not only the labels, but are not perfectly tangent circles and also I can't get perfection the third row of discs

Comment: Sorry, did not see that upon initial inspection. Usually better to explicitly specify exactly what the problems you are trying to address. But, had I not been in a hurry I might have noticed it -- luckily others were more observant that I was.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since all answers are using tikz, just for fun using the modest `\textcircled`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[letterspace=-125]{microtype}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\def\K{\textcircled{\scriptsize{\bfseries K}}}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{6}{\begin{minipage}[c]{2cm}
\lsstyle\sffamily\lineskip1.25pt
\lineskiplimit50pt %large enough ... 
\centering
\K\\\K\K\\\K\K\K\\\K\K\K\K\\\K\K\K\K\K
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

A similar result can be obtained with the `\Kr` command of the `harmony` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{harmony}
\def\K{\Kr{K}}
\begin{document}
{\parindent0pt\bfseries\centering\obeylines 
\K
\K\K
\K\K\K
\K\K\K\K
\K\K\K\K\K
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19):

A little bit cleaner.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \n in {1,2,3,4}
    \foreach \m in {1,...,\n}
      \node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm] at ($(60:\m cm)+(-\n cm,0)$) {K};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 17):

Is something like this what you want?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0)--(3,0);
\draw[red] (0,0)--(60:3cm);
\draw[red] (3,0)--++(120:3cm);

\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm](a-1) {K};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm](b-1) at (60:1cm) {K};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm](c-1) at (60:2cm) {K};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm](d-1) at (60:3cm) {K};

\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm,right=0mm of a-1](a-2){K};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm,right=0mm of a-2](a-3){K};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm,right=0mm of a-3](a-4){K};

\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm,right=0mm of b-1](b-2){K};
\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm,right=0mm of b-2](b-3){K};

\node[circle,draw,minimum size=1cm,right=0mm of c-1](c-2){K};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16):

Stacking `tikz` balls.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
%\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\savestack{\K}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries K};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\savestack{\C}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries C};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{center}
\setstackgap{L}{1.732cm}% =2cm * sin(60)
\Longstack{\K \\ \K\K \\ \K\K\K  \\ \K\K\K\K}
\qquad
\Longstack{\C \\ \C\C \\ \C\C\C  \\ \C\C\C\C}
\end{center}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

...and just to show some added stacking flexibility:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=15pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,backgrounds}
%\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\savestack{\K}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries K};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\savestack{\C}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm) node {\Huge\sffamily\bfseries C};
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{center}
\setstackgap{L}{1.732cm}% =2cm * sin(60)
\Longstack{\K \\ \K\K \\ \K\K\K  \\ \K\K\K\K}
\qquad
\Longstack{\C \\ \C\C \\ \C\C\C  \\ \C\C\C\C}

\bigskip
\setstackgap{L}{2cm}% =2cm * sin(90)
\Longstack[l]{\K \\ \C\C \\ \K\K\K  \\ \C\C\C\C}
\qquad
\Longstack[r]{\C \\ \K\K \\ \C\C\C  \\ \K\K\K\K}

\end{center}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Another option, with more succinct code than some but less concise than [Manuel's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222136/). This solution uses the `chains` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, varwidth, multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
      node distance=0mm,
      every on chain/.style={draw, circle, minimum width=10mm},
      font=\sffamily\bfseries
    ]
    {[start chain=main going {at=(\tikzchainprevious), shift=(-60:10mm)}]
      \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
          \node (k\i) [on chain] {K};
      \foreach \i in {2,3,4}
        {[start chain=ck\i going left]
          \chainin (k\i);
          \foreach \j in {2,...,\i}
            \node [on chain=going left] {K};
        }
    }
    {[start chain=other going {at=(\tikzchainprevious), shift=(-60:10mm)}, xshift=50mm]
      \foreach \i in {1,...,4}
          \node (c\i) [on chain] {C};
      \foreach \i in {2,3,4}
        {[start chain=cc\i going left]
          \chainin (c\i);
          \foreach \j in {2,...,\i}
            \node [on chain=going left] {C};
        }
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: small change]

Should you require many piles of coins, you might prefer to use a `pic`. The following code defines a `pic` which takes 3 arguments. The first specifies the contents of each coin e.g. `C` or `K`, the second the number of rows in the pyramid e.g. `4`, and the third the minimum diameter of each coin e.g. `10mm`.

A pile of coins can then be defined as

```
\pic [<options>] {coins={<content>}{<rows>}{<diameter>}};
```

`<options>` can be used, for example, to change the colour of the coins or to shift them left or right.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt, varwidth, multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,scopes}
\begin{document}
  \tikzset{
    pics/coins/.style n args={3}{
      code={
        \begin{scope}
          [
            node distance=0mm,
            inner sep=0pt,
            every on chain/.style={draw, circle, minimum width=#3, pic actions},
            font=\sffamily\bfseries,
            start chain=main going {at=(\tikzchainprevious), shift=(-60:#3)},
            pic actions
          ]
          \foreach \i in {1,...,#2}
              \node (#1\i) [on chain] {#1};
          \foreach \i in {2,...,#2}
            {[start chain=c#1\i going left]
              \chainin (#1\i);
              \foreach \j in {2,...,\i}
                \node [on chain=going left] {#1};
            }
        \end{scope}
      },
    },
  }
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pic [inner color=gray!25, outer color=gray!50, draw=gray, text=black] {coins={K}{4}{10mm}};
    \pic [green] at (50mm,0) {coins={C}{8}{5mm}};
    \pic [yshift=-50mm, xshift=25mm, inner color=yellow!50!orange!25, outer color=yellow!50!orange!50, draw=yellow!25!orange!50!black, text=yellow!25!orange!50!black] {coins={1p}{5}{15mm}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: riches]

Comment: Dear CFR, when I compiled appear the message: line 31,32,33 : undefined control sequence \pic

Comment: @benedito You need TikZ/PGF version 3 for this to work. You must have an older version.